# Java: PDFfiles and Textfile

Tags: java

I have PDFfiles sorted and it contains some files that include names.
The Textfile has list of names too.
I'm trying to make a comparison but couldn't get a good result.
Please see the below snippet and give me your recommendations.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int j=0;
        int i=1;
       //reading text file*****************************************
       File file = new File("E:/........../ NamesTextFile.txt");
                List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
                PDFManager pdfManager = new PDFManager();
        while(scan.hasNextLine() && j!=100 ){   
                 String name = scan.nextLine();
                 //if (!names.contains(name)) { 
       while (i<=7){
       pdfManager.setFilePath("E:/........./PDFfilesTest/"+i+".pdf");
       String pdfName=pdfManager.ToText();
       if(pdfName.equals(name) && !names.contains(pdfName))
       /*
       keep reading PDFfilesTest until you receive a different name 
       in the sorted PDFfilesTest, store the name and compare it with 
       the NamesTextFile if it exists then continue reading 
       PDFfilesTest(for every name in)
        */ 

       //eading PDF files reading****************************
        names.add(name);
        }      
                i++;
                scan.close(); 
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: How about starting from formatting your code properly with indent?

Answer (score 0):

if((pdfManager.ToText().contains(name))){
                 System.out.println(pdfManager.ToText());

```
             }else if (!(pdfManager.ToText().contains(name))){
                 System.out.println("whatever");
        ..
```

.
.
.
.